# «Не избалованный» с зависимым словом раздельно?

Tags: орфография, частица-не

«Не избалованный водоемами Крым»... Склоняюсь к раздельному написанию....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По правилу, причастия с зависимым словом пишутся раздельно с "не".

[image: Вот правило.]

https://foxford.ru/wiki/russkiy-yazyk/slitnoe-i-razdelnoe-napisanie-ne-s-prichastiyami